# Downloading Image from Database? Swift

Tags: swift, database, image, download

I have been recently trying to download an image from Firebase and it is simply not cooperating. Any help would be appreciated!

This is the function I used to download the image.

```
   func downloadDefaultProfileImg() {
    let imgRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: myurllol).child("defaultProfilePicture.jpg")
    imgRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) {
        data, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Nice try idiot" + "\(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.image = image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the image variable I have defined at the top of my class:

```
var image: UIImage? = nil
```

And lastly, this is where I call my function:

```
self.downloadDefaultProfileImg()
            guard let defaultProfileImage = self.image else {
                print("nope1")
                return
            }
            
            guard let imageData = defaultProfileImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.4) else {
                print("nope2")
                return
            }
```

"nope1" appears in the console. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: Which "nope" is it? is `self.image` `nil` or is the `jpegData` call failing?

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more precise. It is the self.image failing.

Comment: If you set a debugger breakpoint after `let image =`, what does it say `image` is at that point?

Comment: It says self.image = nil & defaultProfileImage = (UIImage) 0x00.

Comment: I was hoping you'd set the debugger after `let image` in your first code example. What you just posted is from the second code example, correct?

Comment: Oh yes, I apologize. It says that image = (UIImage) nil.

Comment: Okay, so it's not getting an error from Firebase, but the UIImage isn't getting initialized with the data... I'm not sure what the failure mode is for `maxSize` -- are you sure your image is less than 1 MB? And (also very important at this point)  -- are you sure that the data you're getting is really a valid image file?

Comment: My image is 6,667kb. Just to be sure, I increased the max size significantly. I don't see why it would not be a valid image file, but just to be sure, I reuploaded it. It came directly from Adobe royalty free photos so I feel as if that isn't the issue. @jnpdx